# How to convert this symmetric matrix to normal form?

Tags: symmetric-matrices, bilinear-form, matrix-congruences

I have to find the signature of the symmetric matrix $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 &0\\0 &0 &1 &0\\0&1&0 &0\\0& 0 &0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$. Now to find the signature I want to reduce this matrix to normal form by doing congruence operation.But I am stuck as if we do $R_{23}$ then we have to do $C_{23}$.Then our purpose is not satisfied as we get the same matrix.We should be able to transform this matrix to $\begin{pmatrix} I_k & &\\ &-I_{r-k} &\\ & & O\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find signature of $\phi(A,B)=tr(AB)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2348739/how-to-find-signature-of-phia-b-trab)

Comment: @DietrichBurde No because here I want to know how to normalize this matrix.

Comment: Which normal form do you want? The Jordan normal form is of course $J={\rm diag}(1,1,1,-1)$, which coincides with the duplicate result.

Comment: @DietrichBurde We know that given a symmetric matrix $A$ there exists $P$ non singular such that $P^tAP$ is diagonal matrix with entries $1,-1$ and possibly $0$,how to find that diagonal matrix by congruence operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick in situations like this is to first use off-diagonal non-zero entries to produce a non-zero on the diagonal. In your case, adding the third row to the second (and then likewise the third column to the second to preserve symmetry) gives
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0 \\
0&2&1&0 \\
0&1&0&0 \\
0&0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Now you can continue as usual, i.e. by subtracting half of the second row from the third (and likewise for columns):
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0 \\
0&2&0&0 \\
0&0&-1/2&0 \\
0&0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Normalizing (and reordering) the entries gives the signature: $(3,1)$.

Comment: What is the general method?

Comment: It’s a kind of adapted Gaussian elimination. If you have a non-zero element on the diagonal, you can eliminate zeros below it just like in Gaussian elimination, but then you perform the same operations on the columns to restore symmetry (eliminating the zeros in the row of the diagonal entry). Sometimes you can run out of diagonal entries to use but still have non-diagonal non-zero entries left. In this case, you need the trick in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Hint
$$
\left( {\matrix{
   0 & 1  \cr 
   1 & 0  \cr 
 } } \right) = \left( {\matrix{
   { - 1} & 1  \cr 
   1 & 1  \cr 
 } } \right)^{ - 1} \left( {\matrix{
   { - 1} & 0  \cr 
   0 & 1  \cr 
 } } \right)\left( {\matrix{
   { - 1} & 1  \cr 
   1 & 1  \cr 
 } } \right)
$$